# Composition of functions computable in logspace

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, space-complexity

The **bit-graph** of $f\colon \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ is the language:

$\text{BIT}_f := \{\langle x,i \rangle : 1\leq i \leq|f(x)| \text{ and the $i$-th bit of } f(x) \text{ is } 1\}$

It is said that $f$ is **logspace computable** if $\text{BIT}_f$ is decidable in space $O(\log n)$. Decidable means that there exist a Turing Machine $M$ such that:

1. if $\langle x,i \rangle \in \text{BIT}_f$ then $M(\langle x,i \rangle) = 1$
2. if $\langle x,i \rangle \notin \text{BIT}_f$ then $M(\langle x,i \rangle) = 0$

Prove that the composition $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ of two logspace computable functions $f,g$ is also a logspace computable function.

Any hint on this exercise? What I tried so far is playing with the composition of the two Turing Machines associated with $f$ and $g$, but I didn't succeed because it always end up with a case analysis exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is quite simple. We are going to simulate running $M_f$ (the machine for $f$) on $g(x)$. Let $m = |g(x)|$, and note that $\log m = O(\log n)$. In order to do that, we keep track of the location of the input tape head of $M_f$ (this takes $O(\log m)$ space), as well as the contents of the work tapes (which also takes $O(\log m)$ space). Whenever $M_f$ attempts to read from the input tape, we invoke the machine computing $\mathrm{BIT}_g$, which also uses up $O(\log n)$ steps; we know which input $i$ to give, since this is just the location of the head.

Comment: And what happens when M_f needs to know the size of its input, which is |g(x)|? How can it obtain it by just invoking BIT_g?

Comment: How does $M_f$ get to know the size of its input usually? Presumably it scans its input until reaching a blank. You can do the same here (the definition of BIT is hiding this issue).

Comment: Well, this is the problem I see. When it scans the first bit of its input, which should be the "i" value used to invoke BIT_g? Or equivalently, how will it reach a blank if every time it reads from its virtual input tape, there will be a 0 or a 1, depending on the output of BIT_g?

Comment: The definition of BIT just doesn’t make sense, since it doesn’t state what happens if $i$ is out of bounds. Either the length is known ahead of time (answering your question), or you need three possible output values. In any case, this is just a technicality.

Comment: Okay, I understand it might be a technicality. However, I think BIT is well defined, since when $i$ is out of bounds, then the TM that decides the language will output 0. I want to fully understand this since I also have this question in a general logspace reduction.

Comment: Maybe is the given logspace computable definition wrong? In the literature I've seen that the existence of two other languages in logspace that check the two conditions of BIT separately is required. This would allow to obtain the size of g(x) solving the mentioned problem

Comment: It’s a technicality which can be handled in many ways. You choose how.